# Angular Event Tracing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling

I have a new AngularJS application with controllers communicating together via Events.  For example search bar may trigger a search_term_change or a search_clear event which multiple views / controllers need to respond to differently.  Unfortunately there is a bit of a delay (500ms-1s) in searching or worse the clear button.  I wonder if there is some inefficiency on my event hooks.

Is there a way to trace these events in angular? Or will i need to put in significant logging to be able to do so?

Comment: Have you used Chrome Dev Tools? You can add breakpoints to follow the logic in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used logging with time and object/method identifiers.